# cannot read properties of undefined "_id"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

So i'm new to node.js and i've been working on a mini project, a student portal and i am stuck showing relevant courses only based on the students department and level.

student.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const {ensureAuthenticated} = require('../config/auth.js');
const {Student}= require('../models/schema.js');
var axios = require('axios');
var controller = require('../controller.js');

router.get('/register-courses',ensureAuthenticated,function(req, res, next) {
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/student/available-courses')
.then(
 (response)=>{
   console.log(response.data)
   res.render('register-courses',{courses:response.data});
 })
.catch(err=>{
 console.log(err);
}) 
});
router.get('/available-courses', controller.getCourse);

module.exports = router;
```

ive narrowed down the problem to the req.user conditions which if i remove it renders all courses

controller.js

```
var {Course} = require ('./models/schema.js');
var {Student} = require ('./models/schema.js');

exports.getCourse = (req,res) =>{ 

const user = Student.findById(req.user._id); //problem is i cant access currently logged in user
console.log(user);
Course.find({departmentsOffering:user.department, level:user.level})
.then(items=>{
    res.send(items)
})
.catch(
    err=>{
        console.log(err);
    }
)
}
```

Comment: your misunderstanding how to call things, you shouldn't use axios to call self to call a model from within a different middleware, restructure so getCourse returns what it needs and not res.send then you can use it anywhere

Comment: sorry I'm not following really, you said i should restructure getCourse to return what it needs but i can't seem to access req.user from inside it. It is supposed to return courses that have the same department value and level value as the current user. If i were to change the condition inside course.find to something like "departments offering:'Computer-Science'" the API works and returns courses with that value in their department field

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you forgot to add the ensureAuthenticated middleware in your route declaration.

The declaration should be

```
router.get('/available-courses', ensureAuthenticated, controller.getCourse);
```